# Find which customers are likely to order today

Tags: mysql

I have sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(customerid int, orderdate datetime, orderqty int);
INSERT into Orders(customerid, orderdate, orderqty) VALUES
    (1,'2020-11-25',100),(1,'2020-11-27',160),(2,'2020-12-05',3490),
    (1,'2020-11-29',293),(2,'2020-12-07',293),(1,'2020-12-01',382);
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d90aaf/1/0

From this data I want to filter find out if today(or any given date from calender). The user is likely to order. From this data, it's possible that the customerid=1 who has repeat order every 2 days is likely to order on 2020-12-03 again. Ideally I want this to be done only with last 3 orders of every customer.
Output would be like this on 2020-12-03:

```
customerid,last_orderdate,likelytoorder,sum_of_last_3_orderqty
1,2020-12-01,Yes,835
```

Another user here provided this answer:

```
(SELECT o2.*,MAX(ooo.orderdate) AS Latest3 FROM
(SELECT o1.*,MAX(oo.orderdate) AS Latest2 FROM 
(SELECT customerid,MAX(orderdate) AS Latest1 FROM Orders GROUP BY customerid) o1 
JOIN Orders oo ON o1.customerid=oo.customerid AND oo.orderdate<o1.Latest1 GROUP BY o1.customerid) o2
LEFT JOIN Orders ooo ON o2.customerid=ooo.customerid AND ooo.orderdate<o2.Latest2 GROUP BY o2.customerid) o3
JOIN orders oQ ON o3.customerid=oQ.customerid AND oQ.orderdate>=COALESCE(o3.Latest3,o3.Latest2,o3.Latest1)
GROUP BY o3.customerid
```

I tried this.

```
AND DATE(Latest1 + DATEDIFF(Latest1,IFNULL(Latest3,Latest2))/IF(Latest3 IS NULL,1,2)) = CURDATE()
```

But no output. I am not sure how to add to date from datediff and compare it to current date.
What it does is to give the average days difference in order. If it would be possible to work with this to filter it by date. to display only the customers which are likely to order on a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

I took Latest1 and add datediff together to find the day the order likely to be repeated on. The query now looks like this

```
SELECT o3.customerid as "Customer",DATEDIFF(Latest1,IFNULL(Latest3,Latest2))/IF(Latest3 IS NULL,1,2) AS "Last 3 orders average day",SUM(oQ.orderqty) AS "Sum of order quantity for last 3 order", ADDDATE((Latest1),DATEDIFF(Latest1,IFNULL(Latest3,Latest2))/IF(Latest3 IS NULL,1,2)) as "Likely to order on" FROM
(SELECT o2.*,MAX(ooo.orderdate) AS Latest3 FROM
(SELECT o1.*,MAX(oo.orderdate) AS Latest2 FROM 
(SELECT customerid,MAX(orderdate) AS Latest1 FROM Orders
GROUP BY customerid) o1 
JOIN Orders oo ON o1.customerid=oo.customerid AND oo.orderdate<o1.Latest1
GROUP BY o1.customerid) o2
LEFT JOIN Orders ooo ON o2.customerid=ooo.customerid AND ooo.orderdate<o2.Latest2
GROUP BY o2.customerid) o3
JOIN orders oQ ON o3.customerid=oQ.customerid AND oQ.orderdate>=COALESCE(o3.Latest3,o3.Latest2,o3.Latest1)
GROUP BY o3.customerid
```

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b8df/6/0

With "likely to order" date. I figured there's no need to write "yes/no" column as it has no use.